# Pivot table formula

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am working on Excel Report (Excel 2013 pivot table). I have a field called [Day of the month] which I dragged onto Columns in the Pivot Layout.

At the end of the column I added a new field USD (USD=Total item Qty/No.of Days).

My problem is when I select 2 or 3 days in the filter[day of the month], the column width is reducing but the formula field USD is not reducing.

Here is what I have so far :

```
Day 1...........................2

Qty USD       Qty   USD    Total USD

10   50        20    30     50+30/count of days i.e 2
```

so i should get 40...

Here date field is filtered..If i select 10 days then column width increases.But my formula field i.e Total USD is not increasing accordingly

How can I write dynamic formula so that my USD field increase /decrease according to filter selection?

---

I want to make clear my previous question

Day   1...........................2

```
  Qty USD       Qty   USD    Total USD

  10   50        20    30     50+30/count of days i.e 2
```

so i should get 40...

Here date field is filtered..If i select 10 days then column width increases.But  my formula field i.e Total USD is not increasing accordingly

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Also, I feel that information is missing. Maybe you can provide some screenshots?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you increase your columns to include 10 days, your formula `Total item Qty/No.of Days` doesn't add up the USD for all 10 days and divide by 10? If so, how is that formula made, did you use the Excel pivot table functionality `Fields, Items, & Sets` or is this just a worksheet formula?

Comment: no the formula is like   =SUM (B7,D7)/count(B7,D7) .....But if i increase days in filter i got Error msg .....   there is already data in sheet1.Do you want to replace it